# What is the material of Spider-Man's "Night Monkey" suit?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home

What is the material of Spider-Man's "Night Monkey" suit? As we can see in the movie *Spider-Man: Far from Home*, it protects him from the attack of the drone which I believe was a bullet. Was it bulletproof?

[image]

The hole in this photo looks like a bullet hole that was caused due to the drones.

Comment: I might have to rewatch the movie, but a pyrotechnic charge (i.e. a bullet "blank") might still leave burn marks on fabric similar to the cigarette burns I have in the seat of my car.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Night Monkey suit only appeared when he was fighting the Fire Elemental monster.

Up to this point, all actions of the drones were carefully crafted *illusions*, holographic projections and pyrotechnics programmed beforehand by Mysterio and his team.

It is only after Mysterio obtains the E.D.I.T.H. sunglasses that they have broader control of actual firepower from both satellite and drone artillery.

Indeed, it is when Spider-Man discovers Mysterio's secret plans do they dial up the lethal weapons to 11.

Consequently, in my opinion, the stealth suit (the proper name) is not made of any special material other than what was available to S.H.I.E.L.D. not necessarily bulletproof Stark tech

Comment: what is the material of the suit is still not answered

Comment: By virtue of elimination, we can agree it is not bulletproof so it’s likely not Kevlar.  In your image there is a hole, tear or burn so it is a fabric of some kind.  Beyond that, It is all speculation